# Pass multi-layer tree Array from Ajax to c#

Tags: c#, ajax

I need to pass multi layer tree array from ajax function to c# code.

```
Ajax code is: 

$.ajax({
    url: '/Index/Index',
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify(arguments),
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (data) {
        //success
    },
    error: function (data) {
        //error
    }
});

c# Code is:
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string[][] HotelList, string[][] DayWiseList, int Season)
```

I can able to pass data from Ajax to C#. but i am not able to getting array list in properly.

In below screen shot, i console array list which i pass from ajax to c#.
[image]

Comment: May be you should to change type from `string[][]` to `object` or `dynamic` and then parse model on server side with the help of reflection, because nesting level, as I understand, is not known in advance.